# After trigger increasing value by 1 in all records instead of the only one being updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

I want the below trigger to update NOA column by +1 only in the row in which the customer address has been changed.

I run a query and only updated customer address in one record, but NOA went from 0 to 1 in all 7 records. How to?

```
create trigger track_updates
on CstmrEng.tblCustomer
after update
as
if (UPDATE(CustomerAddress))

update CstmrEng.tblCustomer
set NOA = NOA +1
```

Comment: Why do you think that the trigger runs on all rows if really only one row is changed?

Comment: Look at your update statement. Sure it updates the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always be using `inserted` in a trigger!

Something like this:

```
create trigger track_updates
on CstmrEng.tblCustomer
after update
as
begin            
    if (UPDATE(CustomerAddress))
    begin
        update c
            set NOA = c.NOA + 1
            from CstmrEng.tblCustomer c join
                 inserted i
                 on c.customerId = i.customerId;  -- or whatever the primary key is
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! Im getting closer, Howeever im getting this error:



Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure track_updates2, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0]
Ambiguous column name 'NOA'.




The second NOA in 'NOA+1' is ambigious, any way of fixing that?